# Image in Memory as div background-image

Tags: image, html, background-image, dotnetnuke, binary-data

I'm doing all of this in a DotNetNuke module.

I have some images that I load from a database as byte data. Originally, I was converting the byte data to a `Drawing.Image`, resizing it, then converting it back to a byte before doing a `Response.BinaryWrite`. This was all taking a place in .aspx.

Meanwhile, in the View.ascx I create a `div` in the code as part of a jquery and had the `background-image` point to the url of previously mentioned .aspx. I had passed in a parameter within the url string to get different images and this all worked fine.

However, here's the problem; I learned that using a .aspx within a DNN module can create a security issue among other problems. Therefore, I'm now looking for alternatives for displaying the images as a background within the `div` tag.

Is there a way to load the image into memory and set the div's background to that memory image and will that work across the latest versions of IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, and Chrome? I'm open to other alternatives and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are validating the users access to the resource, there is no security risk with doing this.

Comment: Oh, then all I need to do is add a check then. Thanks!